# regex for string substitution

Tags: java, python, regex, replace, string-substitution

I have a file containing some data records like this:

```
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> "10.983007809025084" .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> "43.721979606737897" .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier> "1234502851114AA" .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.mylab.org/mydata/schema#Node> .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.disit.org/km4city/schema#nodeType> "STRING_STRING_STRING" .
```

In each of this entry I have to substitute the lines like this with a script (java/python or others):

```
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> "10.983007809025084" .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> "43.721979606737897" .
```

adding the `^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>` at the end of the numbers:

```
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> "10.983007809025084"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
<http://www.mylab.org/mydata/resource/1234502851114AA> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> "43.721979606737897"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
```

Can you help me with a regex that help me for the substitution?

Actual regex:

```
(pos#long>\s"\d)
```

It catch only `pos#long> "1`

Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are here long enough to understand that this is not place where you drop your requirements and other people do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to match the lines you want to replace, the regex you want is actually a bit more complex than what you have: `(.+wgs84_pos#(?:long|lat).+) \.`. This will match and capture the existing text in the string.

In Perl, your replacement code would look something like this (I leave the rest of the Perl script up to you):

```
$line =~ s/(.+wgs84_pos\#(?:long|lat).+) \./$1^^<http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema#float> ./g
```

What this does is capture the entirety of the first line, minus the period at the end, then dump it into the new line along with your additional snippet before appending a period.

Comment: I do the replace with Sublime using your regex. This regex is perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

With `(>\s"\d*\.{0,1}\d*"\s\.$)` you can find both numbers if they are at the end of the line. Then you can just append `^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>` to that line.

Alternatively you can replace search for `(>\s"\d*\.{0,1}\d*"\s\.$)` and replace with `$1 ^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>` (tested with notepad++).